# Meaning of the term "Activation of alkene"

Tags: organic-chemistry, terminology

While reading organic texts, I have come across authors referring to "Activation of alkene" what does that mean !? Does it mean to include the alkene in resonance or what else exactly ?

I saw this notation, while reading about Heck reaction:

> The palladium-catalyzed C-C coupling between aryl halides or vinyl halides and activated alkenes in the presence of a base is referred as the "Heck Reaction"

I also observed this while reading about nucleophilic conjugate addition:

> Ordinary nucleophilic additions or 1,2-nucleophilic additions deal mostly with additions to carbonyl compounds. Simple alkene compounds do not show 1,2- reactivity due to lack of polarity, unless the alkene is activated with special substituents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activation of an alkene just means that the double bond has a higher electron density than that of a normal isolated double bond. That is, the electron density in the double bond is greater than the one observed in ethene $\ce{CH2=CH2}$.

Activation, in organic chemistry, generally means the compound displays a greater nucleophilic nature than it normally should due to increased electron density. For example, $\ce{-OCH3}$ group activates benzene when it forms toluidine. This makes the benzene ring more electron rich and so make it easier to react in nucleophilic reactions.

Comment: "Activation of an alkene just means that the double bond has a higher electron density" Does it really? One C atom could have partial negative and the other positive - still more reactive; or two positive - enables it to act as electrophile - why exactly nucleophilic character would be only important?

Comment: The term was used to refer to an $\alpha, \beta$ unsaturated carbonyl in my notes for the Michael reaction. Doesn't that mean it's an electron *deficient* bond?

Comment: Also, the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_reaction) on the Michael reaction has the phrase 'The R" substituent on the activated alkene'. Seems to imply it's electron-deficiency that's meant.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal: please respond if you're available.